# Server Document Root Path in PHP

Tags: php, absolute-path

I have a php code line like below

```
$files = glob('myFolder/*');
```

I want to use absolute path to myFolder in above by using server document root, like below

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/myFolder/"
```

It should be like below

```
$files = glob('$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/myFolder/*"');
```

But this is not working

How to correct this?

Actually I am trying to do this:

```
<?php
//Delete All files from folder
// $files = glob('myFolder/*');

$files = glob($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/myFolder/*");

foreach($files as $file){
if(is_file($file))
unlink($file);
} 
?>
```

Code below is working

```
$files = glob('myFolder/*');
```

This below is not working

```
$files = glob($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/myFolder/*");
```

I want to use absolute path to myFolder

Comment: 1) at the beginning of the script, include `error_reporting(E_ALL)` in case `unlink` is throwing errors.  2) Inside the foreach, echo `$file` so you can verify what it *can* see.
Try both of these then update your post with the results.

Comment: You need to tell us what's wrong the the path it's trying to glob: `var_dump($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/myFolder/*");`

Comment: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] returns the path of Your root (e.g. public_html) folder, can You explain Your folder strucuture? Where is Your .php file, and myFolder ?

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: File and folder were not at root. Got it fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Its very useful question @HiroshiRana.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`$files = glob($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/myFolder/*");`

Comment: not working. Please see question edits.