# Simple php navigation includes

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a simple php page using includes and I'm finding it hard to navigate the urls using ../ to locate the right path to the folder.

Is there an easy way to construct a simple php navigation. Only doing it locally without using mysql and etc.

```
<a class="list-group-item" href="index.php">Overview &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-tachometer fa-fw"></i></a>
<a class="list-group-item" href="ticket/tickets.php">Tickets &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-ticket fa-fw"></i></a>


<? php 
    $indexURL = ('project/*');
?>
<div id="sidebar" class="sample">
    <div class="search">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search..."> <i class="fa fa-search fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group">
        <a class="list-group-item" href="<?php echo '$indexURL' ?>/index.php">Overview &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-tachometer fa-fw"></i></a>
```

Comment: Use absolute urls: `/ticket/tickets.php`, etc. or use a variable that defines the root and you can prefix to each url.

Comment: How can I use variable to define the root? that's what I've been trying to find :(

Comment: Refer to this for getting the document root.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211231/server-document-root-path-in-php

Comment: can you give me an example how to do it inside href :( <? php 
    $indexURL = ('project/*');
?>
<div id="sidebar" class="sample">
    <div class="search">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search..."> <i class="fa fa-search fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group">
        <a class="list-group-item" href="<?php echo '$indexURL' ?>/index.php">Overview &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-tachometer fa-fw"></i></a>

Comment: @joroen I tried using absolute urls but when im in the ticket.php page then go back to index.php the url is stuck in /tickets/index.php. Index.php is outside /ticket/

Answer (score 0):

This line will write out $indexURL, literally.  If you want the value of $indexURL, remove the single quotes.

```
<?php echo '$indexURL' ?>
```

Comment: <?php echo $indexURL ?> instead? that gave me error.

Comment: Remove the space between <? and php which wrap the assignment statement.

Comment: I did that and it just output as project/$indexURL than actually going to the page :/

Comment: nvm was doing the echo wrong and forgot to put semi-colon

Answer (score 0):

To get absolute path to your document root use:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

This should return c:\wamp\www
Or /opt/www 
Or your location to apache document root.
To test this simply type:

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

To get the folder location use

```
echo basename(__DIR__);
```

will return the current directory name only

```
echo basename(__FILE__);
```

will return the current file name only

```
echo basename(dirname(__FILE__));
```

Will return the location of the php file that is running the code.
Lets take 3 files for example

```
home.php
test/pics.php
test/images/editor.php
```

in your pics.php you need to use functions in editor.php, so you use

Pics.php:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/editor.php';
```

Home.php

```
require_once 'test/pics.php';
```